# unable to display search results OOP

Tags: php, oop, search

This code section is used on another page where results are to be displayed.

```
<?php

require 'core/init.php'; //all classes are contained in here.
$general->logged_out_protect();
$search = $_POST['search'];
if ($users->user_exists($_POST['search']) == false) {
    $errors[] = "Sorry that username doesn't exists";
} else
if ($users->user_exists($_POST['search']) == true) {
    // i would like to display username which is in the user_exists if the above condition is met.
    }
}
?>
```

//This is function user_exists in which i determine if username is in database then after i display the username.

```
public function user_exists($username) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: the major problem i face with above code is displaying the search results.incase some issues that i have not seen,let me know.

Comment: you can always edit your question. currently it really need it since its not obvious what your problem is

Comment: 1.`SELECT*FROM` should be `SELECT * FROM` 2. Binding should go before executing 3. For binding in a query must present a placeholder.

Comment: You're not going to gain any bytes from doing `SELECT*FROM` - Make it breathe `SELECT * FROM`

Answer (score 1):

You either use PDO and execute: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
```

or mysqli and bind param and **then** execute: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();
```

note if you use prepare:

- you don't need to escape your input string
- you need to use `?` as placeholder or `:placeholder` : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

## Query debugging:

to get mysqli errors use: `or die(mysqli_error($db)` after your execute or query call.

## solution

1. change the order of your execute() and bind_param() (first bind_param() **then** execute())
2. your sql query should be: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like '%$?%'"`

Answer (score 0):

Several programming suggestions.

1. PHP is dynamic typed, so a variable or function result value, may return different variable types, stick to single type.

In some circumstances `null` could be used, instead of the predefined type, for example,
returning `null` when a search is not found, instead of an integer value.

2. For PHP, use comments to determine which data type a function receives or returns.

Before.

```
public function user_exists($username) {
```

After.

```
public /* bool */ function user_exists(/* string */ $username) {
```

It doesn't change your code logic, but, helps any programmer, either you or another person, to understand the logic of the function.

3. When using a "try" sentence in a function that returns a value (non `void` function), only use a single "try" sentence.
4. When using a "try" sentence in a function that returns a value (non `void` function), declare the local variables with empty values before the "try", and make all assignaments inside the "try":

Before.

```
public function user_exists($username) {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

After.

```
public function user_exists($username) {
    $query = null;

    try{
      $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
      $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

This allows you to read their values in the `catch` section when an exception is generated,
or to clean them either in the `catch` sections or `finally` sections.

Even that the PHP enviroment is garbaged collected as: Java, ".Net", and other programming enviroments, some good "House Cleaning" is welcome, and helps you have more control of your programming logic.

5. When using a "try" sentence in a function that returns a value (non `void` function), assign the exception result to a local variable, and transfer the `die` to a "finally" section.

Example:

```
public function user_exists($username) {
    $query = null;
    $ExceptionMsg = "";
    $AnyException = false;

    try{
      $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
      $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        $ExceptionMsg = $e->getMessage();
        $AnyException = true;
    } finally{
        if ($AnyException)
          die($ExceptionMsg);
    }
}
```

Cheers.